# Virtualbox doesn't run on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, grub2, virtualbox

I've installed virtualbox-5.0 successfully on ubuntu 16.04. During installation I didn't get any error message, but now I can't launch it.
I had enabled hardware virtualization technology (VT-x) for use in Virtualbox befor installation and also I test two installation way : using ubuntu repository and downloading .deb ([following this link](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads))

[image: here is the screen shot of launching result that system does nothing.]

I don't know why and what should I do.

The output of `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` command is here:
[image: result of unity support test command]

> **Update (OCT24):**

When I edit grub config file (`/etc/default/grub`) to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`
 and `update grub`, Virtualbox appears and launches, but system runs very very slow that I can't even click on something properly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Reboot of host and **not** running VirtualBox as root may help.

Comment: Can you post the output for the command ```virtualbox``` in the terminal?

Comment: @AmeyaVS it doesn't have any output and seems to run, but nothing happens! I've inserted a photo in first post in my question about entering virtualbox command.

Comment: @Takkat I did it. nothing happend and still it doesn't launch.:( (https://ibb.co/cuo41v)

Comment: no, you didn't you are still root.

Comment: Kindly run with your user account (**not root user**), and let us know.

Comment: @Takkat I did it and still have problem . https://ibb.co/jd53Ta

Comment: @AmeyaVS thanks, here you are https://ibb.co/jd53Ta . Nothing happened.

Comment: From the screenshot I see that the VirtualBox icon is having the **mark** for an application launched. Can you please see if the Virtualbox is running in the background?

Comment: @AmeyaVS yes, it seems to be running in the background! here is the snapshot : https://ibb.co/ivJ74F

Comment: Try restarting the system and try again, since I feel the earlier instances which were run with root privileges are still running in the background.

Comment: @AmeyaVS here you are : https://ibb.co/dQ68da

Comment: Can you try ```Alt+Tab``` it to switch it to the desktop?

Comment: @AmeyaVS When I press Alt+Tab, virtualbox and other open applications appear, but still when I choose virtualbox, nothing happens.

Comment: @FatemehAbdollahei Reinstall vbox ?

Comment: Exactly which link did you install? i386 or AMD64.  Please reinstall using the correct architecture.

Comment: I reinstalled now using apt-get install virtualbox. (my system arch is X86) but still have same problem.

Comment: @FatemehAbdollahei What happens when you click the ubuntu icon and search for it?

Comment: @Tim it shows virtualbox icon.

Comment: @FatemehAbdollahei But no window? Has it opened on another "imaginary" secondary screen or something?

Comment: @Tim Wow! my God! I had second screen and now my problem is solved! thanks! please write your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you’ve said, it sounds like VirtualBox is open.

Sometimes, especially on laptops, you can get a “phantom” screen - when Ubuntu thinks there’s a screen connected to the HDMI output (or equivalent) when there’s nothing there.

Ubuntu may still try to display applications on this phantom screen. Try disabling the external screen to avoid this issue. When you do disable it, all of the applications on that screen should move to the only screen connected - the real screen.